# If $\lVert x_0\rVert<1,$ exists $t_0\in\mathbb{K}$ such that $\lVert x_0+t_0y_0\rVert=1.$

Tags: general-topology, functional-analysis

> Let $E$ be a normed vector space over $\mathbb{K}$, of infinite dimension.
>
> A neighbourhood of a point $x_0$ on the weak topology $\sigma(E,E^*)$ is written on the following way:$\mathscr{V}=V(x_0;T_1,T_2,...,T_n;\epsilon).$
> If $\lVert x_0\rVert<1$ show that exists $t_0\in \mathbb{K}$ such that $x_0+t_0y_0$ and $\lVert x_0+t_0y_0\rVert=1$.

It was suggested to me to consider the function:
$g:[0,+\infty[\to\mathbb{R}$ such that $g(t)=\lVert x_0+ty_0\rVert$.

However I am stuck. I am still trying to get the hang on problems involving the weak topology.

**Question:**

How should I solve this problem?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Intermediate Value Theorem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Find $y_0 \neq 0$ in the common kernel of the $T_i$.

Then $x_0 + ty_0$ is in $\mathcal{V}$ for all scalars $t \in \Bbb K$, as $$\forall i \in \{1,\ldots,n\}: |T_i(x_0+ty_0) - T_i(x_0)|  =tT_i(y_0)= 0 < \varepsilon$$

With your $g$, which is well-defined and continuous from $\Bbb [0,+\infty)$ to $\Bbb R$, 
then $g(0)=\|x_0\| < 1$ and for large enough $t$, $g(x) > 1$. The intermediate value theorem does the rest, $[0,+\infty)$ being connected.